# Kubernetes default user RBAC docker-desktop

Tags: kubernetes, rbac

I'm trying to understand RBAC. I've already know that it's supposed to limit access to specific roles/service accounts.

For instance I configure user 'john' to have only access to 'pods' and the verbs 'get' and 'list'.

The problem is, the other person would download the chart, not configure user 'john' and use their own 'docker-desktop' default admin role, which gives them permissions over everything, and they can see everything there, secrets, etc...

Am I misunderstanding something? Can someone help?
I don't understand the value of RBAC, if user can just download the chart, and with their admin account, see all of the application, secrets, etc...

I've tried checking google for this and nothing came up.

Comment: In the hosted Kubernetes environments I use in my day job, as a developer I do _not_ have cluster-admin access and I can't just install anything anywhere.  Cluster-admin access exists, but users don't generally have it.  (Compare to a root account existing on desktop Linux or MacOS, but most operations being done as an unprivileged user.)

Comment: I think thats the case. RBAC only works if you have a shared pre installed environment. If you do have access to the chart, you can view everything you want, bypassing all the security measures put in place by it.